# Why do a lot of publications ignore better results from other papers // compare only to old results (example in deep learning and biomed)

Tags: ethics, publishability

Before starting my experiments using open-access data, I compiled a list of the current publications using this same data and their results. I regularly faced the following situations when reading these papers:

- Publications with better results are not mentioned in the comparison/previous work. Not only recent papers, which could have been published after the original submission date, but often older papers.
- The benchmark used for comparison are "old". While robust they are not representative of the results obtained during recent years, or what could be call "state-of-the-art".
- Additionally results from these benchmark, or even "state-of-the-art" papers, are recomputed with lower results (the motivation may be to get similar experiment settings).
- The experiment setup used in the original and subsequent papers solving the same tasks are not used. The results are often still compared to the original work.

As a result, there are several papers claiming to obtain the "best" results, to be "state-of-the-art" or justifying the modifications they made to their experiments by showing they outperform other results when really they don't. I often find papers published in 2022/2023 which results are outperformed by papers published in 2019.

**Specification**: I am working in deep learning and biomed/medical imaging. The reasons may be field-specific (especially considering all the issue I mentioned, tho I am certain some of these can be found in a lot of experimental fields), but I am also looking to know pure academic reasons (i.e. possible explanation: publication is easier? students pressured into obtaining good results?) and if it happens in other fields what are the reasons.

**Question:**
**Why is it done?**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152327/discussion-on-question-by-jackred-why-do-a-lot-of-publications-ignore-better-res); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that there are three factors here.

- Like in all fields, there are some lazy and opportunistic practices. Researchers are doubly disincentivized from doing things like hyper-parameter optimization over the benchmark models: first because it is tedious and time consuming, and second because making the benchmark model work better will weaken the claims they can make about their new model.
- Ideally, the referees are the counter force that will prevent authors from getting away with too much. However, deep learning is a bit of a mess in this regard, because there are so many papers, and there are only a few places where algorithms can really be tested apples-to-apples. In many cases, the only way to prove that a benchmark algorithm can do better than the authors claim is to look at the source code, find the problem, and ask the authors to rerun it (or rerun it yourself). This is way too much work for most reviewers. The other counter-force should be the  authors' concern for their reputations, but in deep learning, reputations are based on "breakthroughs" rather than consistent reliability and rigor.
- As a result of the above, a lot of junk gets published every year. Most of it is harmless because most of it doesn't get much attention anyway. However, there is a certain "buyer beware" when looking all papers except for the most famous. And so it wouldn't really be reasonable to expect authors to identify every relevant claim, validate them, and then use the good ones as benchmarks. Rather, authors only bother comparing themselves against the widely accepted (pre-validated) ones.

It is admirable that you have been watching the literature so closely. But, I would advise you to be skeptical toward some of the published claims. For example, I once found a paper that claimed that it could do unsupervised clustering (put all the dogs in one pile, cats in another pile, etc.) without being told anything about the classes *a priori*. This seemed useful, and the idea seemed like it could work, so I spent a few days implementing the algorithm and doing some sanity checks. I eventually realized that the authors had neglected to mention a key limitation: the algorithm only works if all classes have the same number of exemplars. This assumption may be true for certain popular test datasets, but in "real life," the whole point of doing unsupervised clustering rather than supervised classification is precisely because you don't know what's in your dataset. So that was a waste, and I learned to be more skeptical of papers that made strong claims but hadn't been widely adopted.

Finally, I wouldn't necessarily assume that older is worse. For example, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.00390) Tel Aviv U / Facebook AI paper from 2022 indeed outperforms U-Net from 2015 on a biomedical segmentation task, but only slightly (mIOU from 66 to 69). Is it worth trading a well-established and simple model like U-Net for a much more complicated diffusion model in exchange for 3 points? Your mileage may vary.

Comment: good insight thank you.

Comment: Yeah, Unet is not the best example. I also beat all the paper I found with a optimised Unet and good data augmentation. However as I mentioned and you highlighted, the benchmark are not optimised, so the comparison is done with "worse" model rather than the metrics reportef by optimised model in other paper

Comment: Also I can echo the advice on skepticism. I recently read new papers to update my tables as I'm writing up my thesis, and I found some ... interesting results... let's say. So I started doubting a bit and I'm glad I can read you advice, as validation

Answer (score 5):

Carelessness and the (perceived) need to portray the new method as outperforming existing ones certainly make their contributions here.

Some other possible reasons are:

1. There is no software provided with the papers supposedly introducing better methods, or potentially existing software may run into trouble when used by users other than the original authors.
2. The supposedly optimal performance in some papers may not reproduce in the hands of the authors of the newer paper.
3. The supposedly optimal performance in some papers may be a product of a lot of tuning and experimenting in order to achieve an "optimal" result, which a normal user other than the paper authors will not normally do and potentially not be able to do, at least not on a different data set. If authors play around a lot with tuning in order to achieve a good performance on certain data sets, there will be heavy selection bias.
4. Furthermore, a normal user cannot be expected to put a monumental effort into tuning, and the authors of a new paper will often justify the fact that older methods are not used in the optimal way by referring to a straightforward use that could be realistic by a normal user in practice. (They may also think that they shouldn't spend an all too large amount of their own time into making competing algorithms perform as well as possible, not only because they want to make their own method win, but also because it may indeed take too much time that you really only want to spend on your own algorithm).

Your skepticism is justified anyway though. My aim is not to excuse anybody. As a statistician by the way I am often astonished by the way many researchers in computer science seem to think that "optimal" performance on a handful of benchmark data sets that everyone is using is a reliable indicator for good performance on new data sets. If that performance on the few benchmark data sets even is really optimal, that is.